# submodel, subclass or subcontroller ruby on rails references

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am busy making a ruby on rails app.

I want to make an model that contains a text model, a picture model and a link model. Every model can have comments, But i don't want to make different comment models for the text, picture and link model. Is it possible to make a media model witch has a subclass(or how it is called) aka: picture model, text model and link model. Or is there an other clean way to do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create Comment model that has [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations):

```
# Comment model
belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true

# Other model that should has comments
has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
```

You can add above line to every model that needs comments. In order to have polymorphic association you need to have those columns in comments table in db:

```
commentable_id   - int
commentable_type - string
```

You can also use some plugin for comments, on example [this](http://github.com/jackdempsey/acts_as_commentable).

Comment: Is it possible to remove the commentable_type in the database (I wont use @comment.text, @comment.picture, @comment.link)?

Comment: @kaibakker: if you have 3 different models for text, picture and link each with its own id, then you need to have `commentable_type` because you need to know to which model this comment belongs. You can have only `comment_id` if you do it in the way @corroded proposed - so only one table in db for 3 models that inherit from `Media` model.

Answer (score 0):

You're right on track. You can have a media model that has_many comments. You can then do extends Media in your Picture, Link and Text models

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it possible to add for evert type of media a new database table with comments, text_comment, picture_comment and link_comment. they could be made while migrating, the only problem is how do i call information from these databases?